# Why can't I execute this update on a local table with a join to a linked one?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a local table in ms access and a linked one from an excel spreadsheet. And this code isn't working because of the linked table:

```
UPDATE 
   Local_table
   INNER JOIN Linked_table
      ON Local_table.Field1 = Linked_table.Field1
SET 
   Local_table.Field2 = Linked_table.Field2,
   Local_table.Field3 = Linked_table.Field3;
```

I get an error from access saying I can't modify data in an external table. If I convert Linked_table to a local one, the query works and no changes are made to local copy of Linked_table. I'd like to avoid this procedure in order to had an actualized version of Linked_table every time I open my db. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post full error message (not your para-phrasing of it) to be sure of issue? I ask because code here attempts to update local table using linked table data.

Comment: I have no problem using a linked Excel worksheet to update a local table. Cannot replicate issue. See nothing wrong with the posted SQL.